# How to center a TextField with spaces at the end?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, textfield

I've got an application in which some text expands from the center of a TextField one letter at a time. It works just fine as long as there are no spaces, but as soon as a space is reached in the string, it is ignored until a non-space is reached, at which point the text centers itself in the TextField.

`myText` is a TextField on the stage with centered text as its default alignment.

```
// Write the words
var charBetweenWords:String = " ";
var whatToWrite:String = "THERE ARE 200 BARRELS OF OIL IN ONE TANKER TRUCK";
whatToWrite = whatToWrite.split(" ").join(charBetweenWords);
var wordTimer:Timer = new Timer(100, 1);
wordTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, wordHandler);
function wordHandler(e:TimerEvent)
{
    if (whatToWrite.length > 0)
    {
        myText.appendText(whatToWrite.substr(0, 1));
        whatToWrite = whatToWrite.substr(1);
        wordTimer = new Timer(5, 1);
        wordTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, wordHandler);
        wordTimer.start();
    }
    else
    {
        // Done
    }
}
wordTimer.start();
```

I've considered replacing the spaces with a non-space (but still whitespace) character like /u0020, but the font I'm using doesn't appear to support that. No spaces appear at all when I do that (but a trace of `whatToWrite` returns boxes between the words).

The Flash IDE doesn't center text considering spaces at the end. `myText` is placed in the Flash IDE and not initialized in code.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: As an aside, you only need to create one timer.

Comment: I have reproduced this.  An interesting problem.

Comment: Right?
Yeah I only need one timer - good point. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better way (that would be great if someone found a better way), but for now, this is the solution/hack I came up with:  (single line only)

```
var whatToWrite:String = "THERE ARE 200 BARRELS OF OIL IN ONE TANKER TRUCK";    
var wordTimer:Timer = new Timer(100, 1);
wordTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, wordHandler);

//set the the auto size to left so the width matches the text width
myText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

function wordHandler(e:TimerEvent)
{
    if (whatToWrite.length > 0){
        //if the new character to add is a space, replace it with an underscore
        var newChar:String = whatToWrite.substr(0, 1);
        var charToAdd = newChar == " " ? "_" : newChar;
        myText.appendText(charToAdd);

        whatToWrite = whatToWrite.substr(1);

        wordTimer.reset();
        wordTimer.delay = 150;
        wordTimer.start();

        //center the text field manually
        myText.x = (stage.stageWidth - myText.width) * 0.5;

        //if it was originally a space, take off the underscore and make it a space again.
        if(newChar == " ") myText.text = myText.text.substring(0,myText.text.length-1) + " ";

    }
    else
    {
        // Done
    }
}

wordTimer.start();
```

If you need multiple lines, you'd have to programatically split up each line into it's own text field.

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Wish it worked for multiple lines, but like you said I'm going to have to programatically split the text up line by line. I'm... okay with this.

Comment: Using TextLineMetrics you could handle multiple lines. Still the best way is to create a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to create a custom class and use masking with a full textfield that slides in. As the textfield slides in you expand the custom class size and you will get a smoother result. But anyway you can get very precise result using the TextLineMetrics class that gives a bunch of info about all characters in a text. A simpler way is to get the boundaries of the characters:

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var whatToWrite:String = "THERE ARE 200 BARRELS OF OIL IN ONE TANKER TRUCK";
var wordTimer:Timer = new Timer(25);
wordTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, wordHandler);
wordTimer.start();
var textWidth:Number = 0;
function wordHandler(e:TimerEvent)
{
    if (whatToWrite.length)
    {
        myText.appendText(whatToWrite.substr(0, 1));
        var rect:Rectangle = myText.getCharBoundaries(myText.text.length - 1)       
        textWidth += rect.width;        
        myText.width = textWidth + 5//compensate for rect with + 5
        whatToWrite = whatToWrite.substr(1);
        myText.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - myText.width / 2
    }
    else
    {
        wordTimer.stop();
    }
}
```